# spring integration kafka xml exception

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using the Spring Integration Kafka 1.3.0 version,but I still get the exception like below. So any idea to solve this problem ?

```
Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0':
Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument 
is required; it must not be null
```

My xml file is like:

```
<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                    kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
                                    auto-startup="false"
                                    channel="inputToKafka"
                                    order="3"
        >
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="0" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="5" keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500"/>

<bean id="producerProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms">3600000</prop>
            <prop key="message.send.max.retries">5</prop>
            <prop key="serializer.class">kafka.serializer.StringEncoder</prop>
            <prop key="request.required.acks">1</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext"
    producer-properties="producerProperties">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="127.0.0.1:9092"
                   topic="test"
                   compression-type="default"/>
    </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where that message came from - when asking questions like this, always include the full stack trace - it makes it much easier to determine the problem.

I pasted your config into a test, but I didn't get that error, I got errors about missing encoders for the keys and values.

This worked for me...

```
<bean id="kafkaEncoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringEncoder" />

<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext"
    producer-properties="producerProperties">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration
            key-encoder="kafkaEncoder" value-encoder="kafkaEncoder"
            broker-list="127.0.0.1:9092" topic="test" compression-type="none" />
    </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>
```

Note that `default` is not a supported compression type; options are currently `none`, `gzip` or `snappy`.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I solved the problem, it's the spring-integration-kafka version problem. v1.3.0 works perfectly, but v1.0.0 is missing some configuration as far as I know.

Comment: 1.0.0 is very old it's not "missing" configuration, it's just that more configuration was added in later versions.